# Unable to plot AUC using ggplot

Tags: python, plot, roc, auc, python-ggplot

I have the following code to plot the ROC curve.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000,n_features=10,n_classes=2, n_informative=4)

X_train = X[:9000]
X_test = X[9000:]

y_train = y[:9000]
y_test = y[9000:]

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

preds = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test,preds)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(fpr=fpr,tpr=tpr))
ggplot(df, aes(x='fpr', y='tpr')) +\
      geom_line() +\
      geom_abline(linetype='dashed')

auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
ggplot(df, aes(x='fpr', ymin=0, ymax='tpr')) +\
      geom_area(alpha=0.2) +\
      geom_line(aes(y='tpr')) +\
      ggtitle("ROC Curve w/ AUC=%s" % str(auc))
```

However, in the second last line it throws an error that " 'int' object is not iterable". Can anyone help me fix the issue as I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the y value for the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x='fpr', y='tpr')) +\
    geom_area(alpha=0.2) +\
    geom_line(aes(y='tpr')) +\
    ggtitle("ROC Curve w/ AUC=%s" % str(auc))
```

should work